# When can CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE throw SecurityException?

Tags: android, exception, android-permissions, android-context

According to Android [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#createPackageContext(java.lang.String,%20int)),

> createPackageContext() throws SecurityException if the Context
>   requested cannot be loaded into the caller's process for security
>   reasons (see CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE for more information}.

What permission does prevent an app's be loaded in another, thereby throwing `SecurityException`?